# Finding if a list of words contains the reverse of a word

Tags: python, list, for-loop, reverse

Given a list  such as

```
['table', 'drawer', 'chair', 'reward', 'radar']
```

How would you make a function/for-loop, to return a list of the words that have their reverse in the list? I'm trying to include only the first instance of a given word

So the result would be:

```
['drawer', 'radar']
```

and not

```
['drawer','reward', 'radar']
```

My code so far returns the latter result:

```
def find_reversals(lst):

    emptylst = []
    match = []

    for word in lst:
        new = word[::-1]
        emptylst.append(new)

    for i in lst:
        for j in emptylst:
            if i == j:
                match.append(i)

    print('{}'.format(match))
```

Comment: Why is `'radar'` in the final list? Palindromes should be added without checking?

Answer (score 4):

You could do the following:

```
lst = ['table', 'drawer', 'chair', 'reward', 'radar']
s = set(lst)

result = []
for word in lst:
    reverse = word[::-1]
    if reverse in s:
        result.append(word)
    s.remove(word)

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['drawer', 'radar']
```

As this uses a set, the complexity is `O(n)` where `n` is the numbers of elements in the list.

Comment: This is not `O(n)` since reversing a string is not constant. Assuming your longest string is `s`, then the time complexity is `O(n*s)`

Comment: @Chrispresso, as a I said is `O(n)` depending only in the number of elements in the list. But you are correct, if you want to consider the strings in the complexity

Comment: Surely it could be `O(n^2)` in a (very extreme) situation with hash collisions?

Comment: @MinionJim, it could be, but the average case is O(n). But yeah the worst case is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the list with two indices, `i` and `j` where `j` starts at `i` (as long as you want palindromes to count)

```
found = set()
a = ['table', 'drawer', 'chair', 'reward', 'radar']
ret = []
for i in range(len(a)): 
    for j in range(i, len(a)): 
       if a[j][::-1] == a[i]: 
           word = ''.join(sorted(a[i])) 
           if word not in found: 
               found.add(word) 
               ret.append(a[i])

# ret = ['drawer', 'radar']
```

The reason yours is double counting is because you are not tracking whether or not something was found. In this case I track it via a `set` and the sorted order of that word.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without sets, and multiple for-loops:

```
lst = ['table', 'drawer', 'chair', 'reward', 'radar']
result = []

for e in lst:
    new_word = e[::-1]    #Make a reverse of a word
    if new_word in lst:
        if e not in result and e[::-1] not in result:    #Check if the word, or a reversed word is in the list, and if not, put it in a list
            result.append(e)

print(result)
```